# discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Command' object has no attribute 'strftime'

Tags: python, discord.py

Im trying to make a bot command where you can ask the bot if it is wednesday or not but i keep getting this error and i have no idea what to do. please help.
this is my code:

```
@client.command(aliases=['wednesdaymydudes', 'wednesday', 'wednesdaycheck'],
                pass_context=True)
async def isitwednesdaymydudes(ctx):
    currentday = time.strftime('%A')
    if currentday == 'Wednesday':
        await ctx.send('It is Wednesday, {}'.format(ctx.message.author.mention))
    else:
        await ctx.send('It is not Wednesday, {}'.format(ctx.message.author.mention))
```

Comment: Do you have another command with a function name `time`? It looks like something else has shadowed the Python module by that name (or you haven't imported it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should be doing for getting the day of the week is

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

day = dt.now()

day_of_week = day.strftime('%A')
```